# Pasting website links into a word document in a very specific format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I recorded a macro for a link that contains "https://www." at the beginning of it, and it works great.

I want to create one macro, regardless of whether it begins with

- http://www.
- https://www.
- https://
- http://

which pastes the link in this specific format. I am coming from Python and am unfamiliar with VBA. In python, I would do something like this:

```
if "http://www." in mylink:
    replace("http://www.", "")
```

for each of the aforementioned bullets.

How would I do something similar in VBA?

Here's my current macro that removes "https://www." and formats the link as desired (underlined, size 10, in parentheses)

```
 `Sub piclink()
'
' piclink Macro
'
'
    Application.Run MacroName:="Normal.NewMacros.PS"
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=12, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.TypeBackspace
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    If Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone Then
        Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    Else
        Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    End If
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeText Text:="("
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.TypeText Text:=")"
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Font.Shrink
    Selection.Font.Shrink
    Selection.Font.Shrink
End Sub`
```

I will note that "Application.Run MacroName:="Normal.NewMacros.PS"" is a simple copy and paste function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
With Selection.Range
  .Paste
  If InStr(.Text, "www.") > 0 Then
    .Text = "(" & Split(.Text, "www.")(1) & ")"
  ElseIf InStr(.Text, "://") > 0 Then
    .Text = "(" & Split(.Text, "://")(1) & ")"
  End If
  .Font.Size = 10
  .Start = .Start + 1
  .End = .End - 1
  .Font.Underline = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for! If I do not want the parentheses underlined, what do I do? I tried putting ".Font.Underline = True" before the parentheses, but it didn't work.